# Synchronize lyrics to music in a video

Tags: sync, lyrics, karaoke

I am wanting to create a video which plays a song in the background and as the person is singing, the screen will display the lyrics. Very similar to a karaoke disc (CD+G) but the song needs to still be played in the background.

I also need to be able to have the font of the lyrics file increased because it will be played back on a normal television and viewed by elderly people (their eyes are not that great).

I've looked at Subtitle / Karaoke editors but none seem to do what I want. Can anyone suggest any software (free or paid) that would help me do this. I will have access to the original lyrics (accessed in Word format) and the song in MP3 format.

Edit:-

Forgot to add, I want to output the actual file to either MP4 or AVI so that I can then burn it to CD / DVD to play in a normal player. Already have Nero so will be using that.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple using Windows Movie Maker :

1. Add your background.
2. Add a duration to your background (duration the sound track).
3. Set your video title (song name).
4. Import song to the video.
5. Add subtitles for lyrics.

Reference : http://techsultan.com/creating-lyrical-video-windows-movie-maker/